# Android: AlarmManager setRepeating is not accurate

Tags: android, alarmmanager

According to docs, seRepeating is not accurate as from API Level 19 and up.. so I have changed my android project to API level 17 but it still not accurate.. any idea? 
My device runs on kitkat... does alarm manager accuracy depends on the android version of your device or the version in which your app is compiled?

Comment: How not accurate?  Like off by a second, a minute, or an hour?  ANd what was the interval for that amount?

Comment: like 10 mins late ..

Comment: normal .set() is pretty accurate though (only ~30 seconds late)

Comment: Is the device a Marshamallow device?  They added in prevention of wake from idle in Marshmallow.

Comment: My device runs on kitkat

Comment: ex. I schedule an event at 10:10... it just executed at 10:21 .... which is annoying

Comment: I think accuracy depends on the api level of your device and not app.. this is annoying :( I need to set accurate repeating alarms by myself

Comment: It may be that they didn't even implement exact repeating-  notice there is no setExactRepeating function, just setInexactRepeating.  As an aside I wrote a timer library that creates a setExactRepeating by using setExact, it may be of use to you.  See http://gabesechansoftware.com/timers-in-android/

Comment: ok thx will check this out

Comment: The link provided is dead